# access database file on different computers at same time

Tags: ms-access

I have an access database which I want to be accessed by multiple users on their computers at same time and If one user made any changes it get immediately reflected to other users also while working on that same file.

Comment: Do you really mean `dropbox` as the tag?

Comment: *immediately reflected to other users* - this is not how an Access frontend works.

Answer (score 1):

You need to split the database to front and back. Each user will take a copy of the front-end to their desktop and the back-end will be saved in a shared network folder.

See instructions on how to do this here: [Split an Access database](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Split-an-Access-database-3015ad18-a3a1-4e9c-a7f3-51b1d73498cc)

Answer (score 0):

Not my own solution, but according to https://www.daniweb.com/programming/databases/threads/90624/multiple-users-updating-simultaneously

you can share an access database to be set for multiple users to edit simultaneously by looking  under TOOLS -> OPTIONS -> ADVANCED and you can choose:

`Open Mode` which allows multiple users to run the database, exclusive doesnt.

"Default Record locking" has choices for:

```
No locks 
All records 
Edited record [I think this is what you're looking for]
```

Toggling `Edited Record` will let your users access the database together, but they may not be able to modify the same record simultaneously.

Here's a picture from the source!

[image]